# Google assistant volume too low, why?

Tags: google, audio-volume

I have Google assistant running on a headless system. The sound output is via a USB sound card but the volume is too low, even with volume set to max in `alsamixer`.

I've been trying to figure out how to enable `pre-amp`, but have been unsuccessful. The current `asoundrc` is:

```
pcm.!default {
 type asym
 capture.pcm "mic"
 playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
 type plug
 slave {
 pcm "hw:0,0"
 format S16_LE
 }
}
pcm.speaker {
 type plug
 slave {
 pcm "hw:2,0"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out.

It's nothing to do with Alsa, rather the Google Assistant has the ability to control volume, i.e. "OK Google, turn it to 10".